# Finding all values x and y of with complex numbers pt.2

Tags: complex-numbers

Thank you for your help last time. This time, the problem is different. It is:
$$\frac{x+yi+2+3i}{2x+2iy-3} = i+2$$
x and y are assumed to be real numbers.

Basically my first trouble is knowing the conjugate of the denominator. Would it be $2x-2iy-3$ or $2x-2iy+3$? Secondly, I am unsure how to multiply the numerator by the denominator. I tried $(x+2)+i(y+3)\cdot (2x-3)+2iy$ or $(x+2)i(y+3) \cdot (2x+3) + 2iy $ depending on what the conjugate of the denominator is. Are either of these on the correct path?

Comment: If $x,y$ are assumed to be real numbers, then you should state that in the question. As for conjugates, they don't really help in this case, all you need to do is basically multiply by the denominator then identify the real and imaginary parts.

Comment: Could you detail how to do that because I don't believe I'm sure.

Comment: Set $z=x+iy$.  Solve $\frac{z+2+3i}{2z-3}=i+2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $2x+2iy-3$ as $(2x-3)+2yi$, so its conjugate is $(2x-3)-2yi$, but you don't need to multiply $(2x-3)+2yi$ by its conjugate. Just note that $$\frac{x+yi+2+3i}{2x+2iy-3} = i+2 \implies x+yi+2+3i=(2x+2iy-3)(i+2).$$

If we write every term in the form $a+bi$ we get $(x+2)+(y+3)i=((2x-3)+2yi)(2+i)$, then $(x+2)+(y+3)i=(4x-2y-6)+(2x+4y-3)i$. This lead us to the system:
\begin{cases}
x + 2 = 4x-2y-6 \\
y+3=2x+4y-3
\end{cases}

with solution $x=\frac{36}{13}$ and $y=\frac{2}{13}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
z = x + iy 
$$
Taking the conjugate we have
$$
z^* = x -iy
$$
we take all the imaginary parts and multiply by a minus sign.

So to your problem we would do 
$$
z =2x - 3 + i 2y 
$$
using what I stated above we find
$$
z^* = 2x - 3 -i2y
$$
we only change the imaginary component so we use that to rationalize the denominator.